# Loading image from DB in Activity OnCreate() with kotlin coroutines Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Trying to set background image from SQLite with Room in OnCreate():

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
 ...
 //Some "findById" etc
 ...
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
        val curPicture = AppDatabase.INSTANCE!!.imageDao().getImage(GameState.curLocation.picId!!)
        withContext(Main) {
            val bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(curPicture.image, 0, curPicture.image!!.size)
            backgroundPicture.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, backgroundPicture.width, backgroundPicture.height, false))
        }
    }
```

But ImageView remains empty.
I'm loading 5 images in 5 different ImageViews with 5 different coroutines at the same time and sometimes few of them become visible.
I'm trying to use the same code from button, it works normal then.
I understand that the problem is somewhere in the Activity lifecycle, but I don't know where exactly.
How to do it right but without LiveData?

Answer (score 0):

I also get these types of issues in the past, it is due to careless assigning of something to a function that does the same functionality but with a small difference like the input method.

So, I started to use the Glide library every time I want to load an image. Just use the following code:

**Gradle Implementation**

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
```

**Glide Code**

```
Glide
    .with(context)
    .load(place your image here as bitmap or path)
    .centerCrop()
    .into(holder.message)
```

Comment: In the end, I have to use Glide, but it's really slow. When I'm changing the background picture, it disappears, I'm seeing blank background for 1/10 sec and then a new picture appears.

Comment: For that, you have to understand how Glide and the native setImageBitmap load an image to the view. In setImageBitmap, the system loads and set the image to the UI in the main thread while Glide loads the image in a separate thread and uses the main thread to update the view taking it more time to load which helps to reduces the work in the main thread. Glide is also caching the image which may also make it slower to load the image( I am not sure whether caching slows down or not).

Comment: I do understand this in general, but it seems strange for me, that the most popular library gave me such a bad experience from the box. It seems like Glide removes the old picture before loading a new one. I need to change the picture without seeing the background (white screen).

Comment: In the end i found this: `Glide.with(this)
.load(photoToLoad.getPath())
.placeholder(imageView.getDrawable())
.into(imageView)`. It works.